# What is the order of searching maven repositories in Android

Tags: android

I had a problem writing android projects,I have a build.grade file as follows. When I build the project, I pull the project dependencies in the order A->B->C->mavenLocal? Or mavenLocal -> C->B->A? Or any other search order? Is it that once a Maven pull is successful there is no further search?Please help me~

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url A }
        maven { url B }
        maven { url C }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```